# Unable to install any packages on VPS server using apt

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, digital-ocean, vps

I want to install some packages but none is working and I don't have ssh access to my server anymore.
The following is what I got trying to install zip...

```
User@sys:# sudo apt install zip
```

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

You might want to run apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.

The following packages have unmet dependencies: openssh-server: Depends: openssh-client (= 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.3) but 1:8.2p1-4ub untuo.2 is to be installed

openssh-sftp-server: Depends: openssh-client (= 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.3)

1-4ubuntu0.2 is to be installed.

but 1:8.2p ubuntu-release-upgrader-core: Depends: python3-distupgrade (= 1:20.04.35) but 1:20.04.36 is to be installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Please what can I do again?

Comment: I have no issue with my VPS (I use Linode). What VPS do you use?